# How can I return an array of objects instead of ids from a Prisma relation table?

Tags: prisma

I am implementing a basic administration panel using Prisma 4.13 and Nest JS. Each administrator has a set of roles, as defined in the schema down below:

```
model Administrator {

  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String    @db.VarChar(255)
  email     String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)

  roles AdministratorRoleAttachment[]

  @@index(fields: [email], name: "email_idx")
  @@map("administrators")
}

enum AdministratorRoles {
  R
  W
}

model AdministratorRole {
  id        Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  roleType  AdministratorRoles @unique @map("role_type")

  attachedAdmins AdministratorRoleAttachment[]

  @@map("administrator_roles")
}

// Relation table (nxn relation)
model AdministratorRoleAttachment {
  administratorId     Int      @map("administrator_id")
  administratorRoleId Int      @map("administrator_role_id")
  createdAt           DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt           DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @map("updated_at")

  attachedAdmin Administrator     @relation(fields: [administratorId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  role          AdministratorRole @relation(fields: [administratorRoleId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([administratorId, administratorRoleId])
  @@unique([administratorId, administratorRoleId])
  @@map("administrator_role_attachments")
}
```

When I create a new admin, I want to return the created object with the roles it has. I wrote some query code, but the `roles` array only includes each role's id.

```
create(input_data: CreateAdminInputData) {
    const administrator = this.prisma.administrator.create({
      data: {
        name: input_data.name,
        email: input_data.email,
        roles: {
          create: input_data.roles.map((role) => ({
            role: {
              connect: {
                id: role.id,
              },
            },
          })),
        },
      },
      include: {
        roles: true, // This line returns an array of ids! 
      },
    });
    return administrator;
  }
```

The client needs the `name` attribute too. Can I get it back without relying on a second query?